# How to use the title of "lady"?

Tags: proper-nouns, forms-of-address

If you had to welcome the writer J K Rowling, would it be appropriate to say "Lady Rowling / Lady J K Rowling, welcome in our school!" or just "Mrs Rowling / Mrs J K Rowling, welcome in our school!". Is Lady specific to female members of the House of Lords, or wives of lords?

Comment: the wikipedia page is excellent. I could copy-paste from there but don't feel like that should be rewarded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_of_address_in_the_United_Kingdom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not normal to use the title "Lady" unless the woman in question has that title.

This is wider than the House of Lords: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady) says '"Lady" is also a formal title in the United Kingdom. "Lady" is used before the family name of a woman with a title of nobility or honorary title suo jure (in her own right), or the wife of a lord, a baronet, laird, or a knight, and also before the first name of the daughter of a duke, marquess, or earl. '

Nor should you call her "Mrs Rowling", because Rowling is her maiden name, not her husband's name.

If you want to use a title, use "Ms Rowling". But in that context, I think most schools in Britain would say just "J K Rowling, welcome to our school"